# Getting the index for a given item in a QTreeView / Model application

Tags: qt

My Qt desktop app was built on the editabletreemodel sample application.  In the sample application in treemodel.cpp there is a mthod called getItem() which takes a QModelIndex as a parameter and returns a pointer to a TreeItem.

This is what the method looks like:

```
TreeItem *TreeModel::getItem(const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (index.isValid()) {
        TreeItem *item = static_cast<TreeItem*>(index.internalPointer());
        if (item)
            return item;
    }
    return rootItem;
}
```

I would like to do the reverse - that is return a QModelIndex for a given TreeItem.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why do you need to know model index of your tree item?

Comment: Its part of an internal drag and drop.  If I drag and drop a leaf (ie something that has no children) its easy.  However if I drag and drop a node that has children and other node with children I need to recurse down through the tree of the dragged node.  The dragged node is easily obtainable as a TreeItem.  The drop node appears as a QModelIndex.  I'm finding changing from one to the other to be troublesome.

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Difficult... very difficult. And directly not possible. And if you use the TreeItem as in the Qt example code you are out of luck. What you can do is:

1. Add a unique identifier to your TreeItem
2. Modify your data function to get this unique id for a user defined role. You are the user who has to define this new role ;-)
3. Use **QModelIndexList QAbstractItemModel::match(...) to find the index for the TreeItem, which returns the unique id for your user role.

Comment: Thank you Greenflow - this is why I have been struggling!  I wonder if I'm trying to do things the wrong way.  Thanks again.